# What does 'verger' mean other than orchard

Tags: vocabulaire

This is from Les 400 Coups at 34:25.  If you remember the movie, it's the part where a student in class is reciting a poem and another student behind him is whispering either the answer or trying to distract him.  The teacher says:

> Si vous vous laviez les oreilles, du Verger, vous entendriez ce qu'on vous souffle par derrière l'épine au cul.

I don't think 'verger' means 'orchard' here but looking in every dictionary known to me I couldn't find a good translation and in the English translation of the film it seems the phrase was not translated.

##########

UPDATE

Actually, it occurs to me that they might be referring to the poem that the student is trying to recite.  So maybe 'du Verger' refers to what the student thought was in the poem but actually was not.

Here's the complete poem

```
 Jean RICHEPIN
1849 - 1926
Épitaphe pour un lièvre

Au temps où les buissons flambent de fleurs vermeilles,
Quand déjà le bout noir de mes longues oreilles
Se voyait par-dessus les seigles encor verts,
Dont je broutais les brins en jouant au travers,
Un jour que, fatigué, je dormais dans mon gîte,
La petits Margot me surprit. Je m'agite,
Je veux fuir. Mais j'étais si faible, si craintif !
Elle me tint dans ses deus bras : je fus captif.
Certe elle m'aimait bien, la gentille maîtresse.
Quelle bonté pour moi, que de soins, de tendresse !
Comme elle me prenait sur ses petits genoux
Et me baisait ! Combien ses baisers m'étaient doux !
Je me rappelle encor la mignonne cachette
Qu'elle m'avait bâtie auprès de sa couchette,
Pleine d'herbes, de fleurs, de soleil, de printemps,
Pour me faire oublier les champs, les libres champs.
Mais quoi ! l'herbe coupée, est-ce donc l'herbe fraîche ?
Mieux vaut l'épine au bois que les fleurs dans la crèche.
Mieux vaut l'indépendance et l'incessant péril
Que l'esclavage avec un éternel avril.
Le vague souvenir de ma première vie
M'obsédant, je sentais je ne sais quelle envie ;
J'étais triste ; et malgré Margot et sa bonté
Je suis mort dans ses bras, faute de liberté.
```

And here's more of the dialogue from the film:

```
00:34:21,962 --> 00:34:24,215
- Mieux vaut l'épine; au bois...
l'épine au bois...

366
00:34:24,293 --> 00:34:25,432
- L'épine où je pense.

367
00:34:25,511 --> 00:34:27,456
- Si vous vous laviez les oreilles,
du Verger,

368
00:34:27,529 --> 00:34:29,510
vous entendriez ce qu'on vous souffle
par derrière.

369
00:34:29,582 --> 00:34:31,135
- L'épine au cul.

370
00:34:31,217 --> 00:34:33,719
- ll me souffle pas, monsieur,
il cherche à me faire tromper.

371
00:34:33,791 --> 00:34:34,799
- Ça suffit, continuez.

372
00:34:34,869 --> 00:34:37,716
-Je ne sais plus où j'en suis,
monsieur.

373
00:34:37,792 --> 00:34:40,982
- Que les fleurs dans la crèche; ...

374
00:34:41,062 --> 00:34:44,989
- Que les fleurs dans la crèche,
mieux vaut l'indépendance.

375
00:34:45,063 --> 00:34:47,352
- Et l'incessant péril...
```

Comment: Why is Verger capitalized? That seems to indicate it's a proper name.

Comment: Sometimes, family names are made of nouns.

Comment: That would be my theory too. The other sort of thing that could go in that slot is an interjection, but this would be an odd one :)

Comment: It can't be anything but a [patronym](https://gw.geneanet.org/pierfit?lang=fr&p=guillaume&n=du+verger) here.

Comment: La particule et l'incise rendent tout autre chose peu probable.

Comment: yea, I think it probably is a proper name.  I was probably thrown off by the 'du' and just forgot that sometimes French names do begin with 'du'.  So I think the solution is that the teacher is calling him by name.  Normally teachers call students by their first names, but sometimes they also call them by their last names.

Comment: @bobsmith76 In the era and class of that movie, it would generally be last names. In that scene, the teacher says 'du Verger', 'Doinel', 'Simonot', all last names.